# PSOC 5 LP negative input on adc delta sigma in differential mode

Tags: adc, psoc

I want to use an adc sigma with negative voltage input, I am using this psoc : CY8CKIT-059 PSoC® 5LP.

It's a bit unclear in the ADC config because the Input range Under the input options says : +-6.144V, but in the graph on the right Under input range show an ADC range between VDDA -250mV and VSSA +100 mV.

So my question is: Can I put a negative input on the adc sigma in differential mode?

Comment: What voltage is VSSA?

Comment: VSSA is at gnd : 0V

Comment: So VSSA + 100mV is not negative and that is your answer.

Comment: Yes but another menu show input +/- 6.144V for level input.